# How to generalise categorical data when grouping by hour?

Tags: pandas, machine-learning, time-series

I have a dataset like below. I have datetime column as index, and another column with categorical variable. **type** is a categorical variable.

```
start_time          type

2019-12-14 09:37:05 R
2019-12-14 09:40:05 D       
2019-12-14 10:06:25 C       
2019-12-14 10:44:21 C       
2019-12-14 10:50:21 R
2019-12-14 11:06:38 D       
2019-12-14 11:29:04 R   
2019-12-14 11:29:04 R
```

Now, I want to resample the data for every one hour. I want resampled data to be something like below

```
start_time              type

2019-12-14 09:00:00     R       
2019-12-14 10:00:00     C               
2019-12-14 11:00:00     D
```

What logic should I implement here to chose what should be the value of **type** every hour? One way is to take maximum times the value repeated in an hour. For ex, at 10:00:00 if **type** C is seen 3 times, D 1 time and R 2 times. I can assign C to timestamp 10:00:00.

What other ways I can handle this scenario? My end goal is to predict the sequence of type for next hours, If RRCD is the previous sequence what would be the next sequence for next few hours?

Thanks

Comment: Why you need first `R` record(`09:37:05`) but not `11:29:04`? Could you add more records + expected `dataframe`?

Comment: I don't need first `R` record. It's just the example I gave. I have added more records in my question. Hope you will get some clarity

Answer (score 0):

You could build a classifier to make predictions ! You could create a dataframe X, with columns corresponding to Day, Month, Year, Hour, DayOfWeek and use something simple like a random forrest to make predictions.

```python
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X)
model.predict(DataYouWantToMakePredictionsOn)
```

Comment: When I resample it into Hour, what would be the value of **type** I give for that hour. The problem is if I resample it into minute interval I would be getting lot of NaN values. If I resample it into Hour interval, I have many values which I can chose between R,C,D